# Codeigniter Ajax Infinite scroll with filter duplicating data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter-3

I want to create pagination page using infinite scroll with filters. I'm using codeigniter. Pagination is working fine. When clicking ckeck box its working but on scroll it is duplicating the data. I had struggle for days. I will be so grateful if you can help me. Thank you.

This is my view code

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
    load_content();
    function load_content(){
            var total_record = 0;
            var total_groups = <?php echo $total_data; ?>;  
        //brand is the checkbox value
            var brand=check_box_values('brand');
            $('#results').load("<?php echo base_url() ?>content/load_more",
             {'group_no':total_record,'brand':brand}, function() {total_record++;});        
     }
        //For passing checkbox values
             function check_box_values(check_box_class){
                        var values = new Array();
                            $("."+check_box_class).each(function() {
                              if($(this).is(':checked')){
                               values.push($(this).val());
                                }
                            });
                        return values;
                    }
        $(".brand").click(function(){
          load_content();
       });

$(window).scroll(function() {       
                if($(window).scrollTop()+$(window).height() >= $('#fooerdivid').offset().top)  
                {           
                   var total_record = 0;
            var total_groups = <?php echo $total_data; ?>;  
        //brand is the checkbox value
            var brand=check_box_values('brand');

                    if(total_record <= total_groups)
                    {
                      loading = true; 
                      $('.loader_image').show(); 
                      $.post('<?php echo site_url() ?>content/load_more',{'group_no': total_record,'brand':brand},
                        function(data){ 
                            if (data != "") {                               
                                $("#results").append(data);                 
                                $('.loader_image').hide();                  
                                total_record++;
                            }
                        });     
                    }
                }
            });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue back when I was trying to achieve the same. The problem was window.scroll trigger AJAX request multiple times with same Params and it results in a duplication of the data. To overcome this issue you can use a flag to check if the request is running or not. Try this script.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var flag = true; //set initial value true for first request
    $(window).scroll(function() {       
                    if($(window).scrollTop()+$(window).height() >= $('#fooerdivid').offset().top)  
                    {          
                       if(flag) //run script if flag is true
                       {
                       flag = false; //script is running
                       var total_record = 0;
                var total_groups = <?php echo $total_data; ?>;  
            //brand is the checkbox value
                var brand=check_box_values('brand');

                        if(total_record <= total_groups)
                        {
                          loading = true; 
                          $('.loader_image').show(); 
                          $.post('<?php echo site_url() ?>content/load_more',{'group_no': total_record,'brand':brand},
                            function(data){ 
                                if (data != "") {                               
                                    $("#results").append(data);                 
                                    $('.loader_image').hide();                  
                                    total_record++;
                                    flag = true; //Script execution completed and next request can be execute
                                }
                            });     
                        }
                      }
                    }
                });
        });
        });
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

### Update

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var flag = true; //set initial value true for first request
   var is_pending = false; //no request is pending

   load_content();
    function load_content(){
           if(flag) //run script if flag is true
                       {
             flag = false; //script is running
            var total_record = 0;
            var total_groups = <?php echo $total_data; ?>;  
        //brand is the checkbox value
            var brand=check_box_values('brand');
            $('#results').load("<?php echo base_url() ?>content/load_more",
             {'group_no':total_record,'brand':brand}, function() {
                  total_record++; 
                  flag = true; 
                  if(is_pending)
                  {  is_pending = false;load_content(); } 
                  });   
           }     
     }
        //For passing checkbox values
             function check_box_values(check_box_class){
                        var values = new Array();
                            $("."+check_box_class).each(function() {
                              if($(this).is(':checked')){
                               values.push($(this).val());
                                }
                            });
                        return values;
                    }
        $(".brand").click(function(){
         if(flag){
          load_content();
         }else{
          is_pending = true;//request is pending
          }
       });

    $(window).scroll(function() {       
                    if($(window).scrollTop()+$(window).height() >= $('#fooerdivid').offset().top)  
                    {          
                       if(flag) //run script if flag is true
                       {
                       flag = false; //script is running
                       var total_record = 0;
                var total_groups = <?php echo $total_data; ?>;  
            //brand is the checkbox value
                var brand=check_box_values('brand');

                        if(total_record <= total_groups)
                        {
                          loading = true; 
                          $('.loader_image').show(); 
                          $.post('<?php echo site_url() ?>content/load_more',{'group_no': total_record,'brand':brand},
                            function(data){ 
                                if (data != "") {                               
                                    $("#results").append(data);                 
                                    $('.loader_image').hide();                  
                                    total_record++;
                                    flag = true; //Script execution completed and next request can be execute
                                }
                            });     
                        }
                      }
                    }
                });
        });
        });
```

Comment: still its duplicating data@Smit Raval

Comment: Check in your console if its sending the same AJAX request multiple times on page scroll?

Comment: If not you might have a problem in your controller.

Comment: its working when I scrolled to end of data and then clicked checkbox(not duplicating).when clicked checkbox before reaching last data its duplicating@Smit Raval

Comment: I have updated my code. Please ignore syntax error as I have not tested it. Check if it works? @DingoGhatr

Comment: still the same.duplicating when not scrolled to the last.@Smit Raval

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167146/discussion-between-smit-raval-and-dingo-ghatr).

Answer (score 0):

Say you send the request to the server. Hay server serv me rows between 1 and 100, then you "append" results into a div. Next you say: hay server send me rows between 1 and 150 and do a "append" to same div again. Then you have the double results

What jou want to do is to empty  `$('#results').empty()` the div before next push and push all 150
Or "append" between 1 and 100 rows and next time you "append" rows between 100 and 150

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add last id on showing data. Here an example

```
// Here sample data
<div class="timeline-item" id="<?= $row->id; ?>">
  <p>Content Data</p>
</div>

// Here sample jquery
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height()) {
        var last_id = $(".timeline-item:last").attr("id");
        var last_date = $(".timeline-item:last").attr("data-date");
        var base_url = $(".row").attr("data-base-url");
        loadMoreData(last_id, last_date, base_url);
    }
});


function loadMoreData(last_id, last_date, base_url){
  $.ajax({
      url: base_url + 'Kpi/timelineData?last_id=' + last_id + '&last_date='+ last_date,
      type: "get",
      beforeSend: function()
      {
          $('.ajax-load').show();
      }
  })
  .done(function(data)
  {
      $('.ajax-load').hide();
      $("#timeline-data").append(data);
  })
  .fail(function(jqXHR, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
  {
      console.log('server not responding...');
  });
}
```

}

Hope can solve your problem.